# iOS : duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 after pod install

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, duplicate-symbol

I am getting error when added a new pod. My initial pod file was

```
#platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'xxxxxx' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TPV Plus
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'EVReflection/MoyaRxSwift'
  pod 'SwifterSwift'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'LGSideMenuController'
  pod 'CCBottomRefreshControl'
  pod 'MaterialComponents/ActivityIndicator'
  pod 'TweeTextField'
  pod 'DropDown'
  pod 'DisPlayers-Audio-Visualizers'
  pod 'MaterialComponents/BottomSheet'
  
#  pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
  pod 'GooglePlaces', '3.6.0'
  pod 'GoogleMaps', '3.6.0'
```

I have commented few and added FirebaseCrashlytics. Below is the updated one

```
#platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'xxxx' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TPV Plus
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
#  pod 'Firebase/Core'
#  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'EVReflection/MoyaRxSwift'
  pod 'SwifterSwift'
#  pod 'Crashlytics'
#  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'LGSideMenuController'
  pod 'CCBottomRefreshControl'
  pod 'MaterialComponents/ActivityIndicator'
  pod 'TweeTextField'
  pod 'DropDown'
  pod 'DisPlayers-Audio-Visualizers'
  pod 'MaterialComponents/BottomSheet'
  
#  pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
  pod 'GooglePlaces', '3.6.0'
  pod 'GoogleMaps', '3.6.0'
  
  pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics'
end
```

But when I build the project getting error error build: 13 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

In the project all other library files are duplicated as shown in picture. The project is git integrated.

[image]

How will I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue happened here. During the git commit, the pod files were committed partially to git. So I deleted the entire pod folder and kept the pod.lock file as such. After that did the pod install. So all the duplicate files were deleted and project is building successfully.